# Jade template, how to pass concrete object to pages?

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a jade template for my node.js project. I would like to send an object to the jade template and pass it to a function inside the page (to render something).

I am sure I send the right stuff from the server like this

```
res.render(__dirname + '/pages/viz.jade', {
    vizJson: newJson,
});
```

in the client I do something like this:

```
script
    sunburst(#{vizJson})
```

Thus, inside a script function, I want to call a function that creates my visualization with some json I created on the server side.

The problem is that when rendered I have something like `sunburst([Object object])`. I also tried to send the stringified version of the JSON but when I do `JSON.parse(#{vizJson})` it complains like `Unexpected token &`.

The json I send is always different and has different level of depths.

Does anyone knows what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I hope this is going to help someone. I solved it like this:

```
script
    sunburst(!{JSON.stringify(vizJson)})
```

Notice the `!` and the `{...}` wrapping the stringify method.

Comment: my json came back like this: `"{\"some_key\":...}"`.  This could be the product of how I got the original json object, but for this example, I wrapped the output in an in-page JSON.parse("{\"some_key\":...}") method.  The object seemed to work fine in the browser.

Comment: Before you do this, make sure that your json object doesn't contain any unescaped user-controllable data! `</script>` tags even inside a literal string in javascript will break the DOM, and allow arbitrary javascript execution (see http://escape.alf.nu/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the note @James. I guess, `!{JSON.stringify(vizJson).replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');}` should do it?

Comment: anyone else getting this error `Converting circular structure to JSON`?

Answer (score 3):

For this to work, you need to stringify on the server.

```
res.render(__dirname + '/pages/viz.jade', {
    vizJson: JSON.stringify(newJson),
});
```

Then, as you mentioned, parse the JSON on the client.

```
script
    sunburst(JSON.parse(#{vizJson}))
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: You don't need to call `JSON.parse` on the client because the code is already inside `script` tags.

Comment: Sorry that didn't worked. That's one of the thing I tried. Thanks anyhow, I found out how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough, for me the solution involved no calls to `JSON.parse`. I stringified my object on the server and just used the `!{vizJson}` method and got my object clientside.

Per the docs, unescaped string interpolation: http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/

Comment: I guess things have changed in 5 years :) thanks for taking the time to post this!

Answer (score 0):

On the JS side, you send back

```
res.render(__dirname + '/pages/viz.jade', {
    vizJson: JSON.stringify(newJson),
});
```

On the HTML side, I have found that something like:

```
JSON.parse( '!{vizJson}' )
```

works.