# Get value in JS sent by NodeJS route

Tags: node.js, pug

I want to capture the value from a variable that it is sent from NodeJS route to a view.
I know that the way to get this value on HTML (Jade) is:

```
#{name_var}
```

But I want to get this value in JS (JQuery) and the only way that I can think is by DOM (for example: create a div with this value that it is hidden and later, get the value by getElementById).

But I think that this data that I send to the view are delicated, it could be have a great security problem...

What do you think? Are there any other 'alternative' for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you dont want to go through the hard way of putting the value first to a dom element and fetch it later to process.

You can directly assign the values to js variable like the same way you did in your html tags.

Like

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    var somevar = "#{serversideValue}";
```

So that while the html is rendered out of the jade template, it will be rendered as

```
script(type='text/javascript').
    var somevar = "passedValue";
```

Also according to the value passed from the router, you can choose whether to use html encoding or not while assigning the value to the js variable like `#{serversideValue}` or `!{serversideValue}`.

Also if you are passing a complete json object via the router variable, then you cannot directly assign it like what we seen above. One way is to `JSON.stringify()` the value when you send it from the router and use `JSON.parse()` in clientside JS to get back the original object.

Also You might want to look at [**this stackoverflow question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437295/jade-template-how-to-pass-concrete-object-to-pages) to get an understanding of the scenario that we discussed now.

Comment: Perfect. It works in the HTML file. You missed something: you have to add a dot to the end of the first line. A want to ask something more... I have checked this code to add it in JQuery (inside $document.ready()) and it is not work because Jquery don't get the value... just convert "#{serversideValue}" as a String. This is not important but I want to know if this is possible.  Thank you very much.

Comment: just check the html source in browser, it should have rendered the value or are you saying it still comes as `"#{serversideValue}"` there? Jquery doesnt make any difference to the case here.